# Storing and fetching values between a specific date range - Data Structure

Tags: java

I want to create a map with key as date (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS). The value will be an integer. If I get a request with start date as 2017-03-01 00:00:00 and end date as 2017-03-01 10:00:00 , I want to iterate over all the dates between the start date and end date in the map and sum all the values. Is there a utility method that I can leverage to simplify the task of the fetching all the data between specific date range in a map? Is there a better data structure that I can look at for this problem statement?

Comment: Use a TreeMap. That's exactly what it's for. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet